# GDB Compiling Issues

Tags: gdb, powerpc

I want to cross compile GDB for powerpc and I've been going through this link (https://benakiva.wordpress.com/2007/01/15/cross-compiling-gdb-for-powerpc-platform/) but on running the command I am getting the following errors:

```
configure: warning: –target=powerpc-linux: invalid host type
configure: warning: –enable-sim-powerpc: invalid host type
configure: error: can only configure for one host and one target at a time
```

Can you help me out with this?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What gdb? Build on what system? I just built gdb 7.9 by configuring it with ../gdb-source/configure --target=powerpc-linux --enable-sim-powerpc without any hassles on Ubuntu 14.04. Make sure you use -- and not –.

Comment: I am getting an issue:                                                                                                       cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Comment: If you don't want warnings being treated as errors configure with something like CGLAGS="-Wno-error" ../gdb-source/configure --target=powerpc-linux --enable-sim-powerpc

Comment: it is showing the following errors:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C compiler cannot create executables

Comment: Which means your compiler is not working, or you have given it wrong flags. Take care of case... config.log should tell you more about error.

Comment: Can you show us the exact configure command you're using, as well as the version of gdb you're compiling? The options should be preceded by `--`, not `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM ships a toolchain that is already enabled to do cross compilation (From x86 to POWER). You might want to try it, if it fits your needs:

[IBM Toolchain - Supported distro  - Native and cross compilers](http://IBM%20Toolchain%20-%20%20Supported%20Linux%20Distributions)